# Why VBA sometimes reconized the next variable (x1Whole) and sometimes not

Tags: excel, vba

I have a first version of the next code in VBA for excel

```
Function findCell(celda As String, rnc As String) As String

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pos As String

    Range("A2").Select

    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=celda, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        pos = 0
    Else
        pos = cell.row
    End If

    findCell = pos

End Function
```

The function recive a string and return the position in number of the column, but After I change a  parameter because I must be find the full contain of the cell. And I change the value lookAt from **x1Part** to **x1Whole**

```
    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=celda, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

When I try to run the macro doesnt work sometimes and show me that value **x1Whole**, but when I run from the editor works.

Comment: How do you run the macro when it doesn't work? From a formula (since it's a function, not a macro). You cannot select a range in a user defined function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you seek a string in a formula as xlPart, you always get the string from your function itself (a good idea, btw). There will be a problem with xlWhole: there may be a case (and if the formula is the only thing in the sheet, it is is the case) that there's no match. `Find` will give an error, if nothing is found, and the formula result will be #N/A.
Below is your code with error handling, resulting in 0 for no match.

```
Function findCell(celda As String, rnc As String) As String

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pos As String

On Error GoTo Nomatch

    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=celda, After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Nomatch:

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        pos = 0
    Else
        pos = cell.Row
    End If

    findCell = pos

End Function
```

Also, I removed `Select("A2")`, and moved it to `After:=Range("A2")`.

Comment: mmm interesting but sorry whats the difference between Select("A2") and After:=Range("A2") 
and sorry another question I dont get what does mean :> Formula in the context thanks in advance

Comment: `Select("A2")` places your cursor to cell A2 and makes it `Activecell`. In Find, the start of your search started from A2 (`After:=ActiveCell`). As in a cell formula `Select`is simply ignored, the search would start from formula position.

Comment: `LookIn:=xlFormulas` means, that your string is searched from formulae, not from cell values (which would be `LookIn:=xlValues`). Try the various options given by Ctrl-F, recording a macro would be useful.